# should Max(n, log(n, 2)) return n if n is a positive integer?

Tags: python, max, big-o, sympy

I had specified `n` is a positive integer but the following code does not work as expect.

```py
>>> n = Symbol('n', integer=True, positive=True)
>>> Max(n, log(n, 2))
```

will output:

```py
Max(n, log(n)/log(2))
```

after add `.rewrite(Piecewise)` after `Max`

```py
>>> Max(n, log(n, 2)).rewrite(Piecewise)
Piecewise((n, n >= log(n)/log(2)), (log(n)/log(2), True))
```

I think if `n` is a positive integer, `n` should always greater than `log(n, 2)`.

Any idea of this result??

and is there any way to make `Max(n, log(n, 2))` return `n`??

Comment: from: https://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/functions.html [Max]

    In common case, when the length of list greater than 2, the task
    is more complicated. Return only the arguments, which are greater
    than others, if it is possible to determine directional relation.

    If is not possible to determine such a relation, return a partially
    evaluated result.

Comment: Hello @ZarakiKenpachi , thanks for your response but i think this document did not answer my question. In this example `Max` only just takes two arguments and `n` is a positive integer so I think `n` should always greater than `log(n)`.

Comment: i know what the result should be, but Max function is so defined that if he can not determine the proper relation then she returns evaluated result.

Comment: Oh, i get it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had open this issue at github, seems like sympy `Max` function didn't implement this situation.

https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/16926